# Displaying success and error messages using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simple javascript code for displaying error messages it works fine now how to add a statement to this code that states when none of these errors are committed display a success message.

`JS`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#update').click(function() {
                var firstname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
                var lasttname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
                if (firstname.length < 2) {
                    $('#em').html('First name cannot be less than 2 characters');
                    return false;
                }
                if (lasttname.length < 2) {
                    $('#em').html('Last name cannot be less than 2 characters');
                    return false;
                }
                if (firstname.length > 15) {
                    $('#em').html('First name cannot be more than 15 characters');
                    return false;
                }
                if (lastname.length > 15) {
                    $('#em').html('Last name cannot be more than 15 characters');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Because you are returning for every invalid case it means that if the code after the last if statement is reached, then you have valid data. So, you can add the success statement right after the last if statement block.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a statement to display `success` at the end of all the `if`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#update').click(function() {
        var firstname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var lasttname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
        if (firstname.length < 2) {
            $('#em').html('First name cannot be less than 2 characters');
            return false;
        }
        if (lasttname.length < 2) {
            $('#em').html('Last name cannot be less than 2 characters');
            return false;
        }
        if (firstname.length > 15) {
            $('#em').html('First name cannot be more than 15 characters');
            return false;
        }
        if (lastname.length > 15) {
            $('#em').html('Last name cannot be more than 15 characters');
            return false;
        }
        $('#em').html('Everything looks fine'); //add a statement here
        return true; //return success
    });
});
```

**Tip :** Since you are already using `jquery`,  instead of using `document.getElementById` user `jquery` version as below:

```
var firstname = $('#fname').val();
var lasttname = $('#lname').val();
```

Comment: actually I am not able to get what should be that last statement an `else` statement didn't  work so what should be that statement.

Comment: If none of the situation suits in the above condition you return success, and submit the `form`, if any..

Answer (score 1):

use `if-else` clauses instead of simple `if` clauses and end with a final else clause displaying success message:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#update').click(function() {
var firstname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lasttname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
if(firstname.length<2)
{
$('#em').html('First name cannot be less than 2 characters');

} else if(lasttname.length<2)
{
$('#em').html('Last name cannot be less than 2 characters');

} else if(firstname.length > 15)
{
$('#em').html('First name cannot be more than 15 characters');

}else if(lastname.length > 15)
{
 $('#em').html('Last name cannot be more than 15 characters');

} else {
    $("#em").html("Congratulations!!!");
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What i can see an extra closing `}` here:

```
} //<------this
});
});
```

so for your question you can add this at the bottom:

```
var isvalid = firstname.length !== 0 && lastname.length !== 0;
if(isvalid){
   $('#em').html('SUCCESS!!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#update').click(function() {
var firstname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lasttname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
if(firstname.length<2)
{
$('#em').html('First name cannot be less than 2 characters');
return false;
}
else if(lasttname.length<2)
{
$('#em').html('Last name cannot be less than 2 characters');
return false;
}
else if(firstname.length > 15)
{
$('#em').html('First name cannot be more than 15 characters');
return false;
}
else if(lastname.length > 15)
{
 $('#em').html('Last name cannot be more than 15 characters');
 return false;
}
else{
$('#em').html('Success');
 return false;
}

});
});
</script>
```